# Percentage increase/decrease of day during a week

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

If I have a number I'm keeping track of for the entire week, and I want to calculate for a given day, what that day's percentage increase/decrease is based off the average number in a week..

So for instance, calorie intake..

If my week looks something like this:

```
mon: 1500,
tue: 1900,
wed: 1800,
thu: 2500,
fri: 2000,
sat: 0,
sun: 0,
total: 9700
```

And I want to know what the percentage increase/decrease is for `Friday`

Here's how I'm doing it but I'm not sure if this is correct..

`(((total/number of days)-fri)/(total/number of days)*100)`

This results in the answer being: `-3.09`% but that doesn't sound right.. the average for the week is `1940` and `2000` would be an increase...

Any thoughts? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `((fri - (total/number of days))/(total/number of days)*100)`